# I want to check internet connection but it show error

Tags: c++

I want to check my internet connection. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Wininet.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    if (InternetCheckConnection("http:\\www.google.com", FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0))
    {
        cout << "You are connected to the Internet" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You are not connected to the Internet" << endl;
    }
}
```

But it shows the following error:

```
C:\Users\icl\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGjaicH.o  n.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `__imp_InternetCheckConnectionA'
C:\Users\icl\Desktop\New folder\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Although `WinInet.lib` is the correct library to link to for `InternetCheckConnection()`, most compilers do not recognize the `#pragma comment` directive, requiring alternative solutions for linking to libraries. On a side note, the URL you are passing to `InternetCheckConnection()` is malformed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using dev-c++

Comment: In Dev-C++, DLL import libs are linked to in the project settings instead of in code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau What should i write in linker?

Comment: see https://sourceforge.net/p/dev-cpp/discussion/128327/thread/1baf9670/, using `wininet` as the lib to add.